# how to do authorized request to web api from different port number

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have following jquery code which successfully make authorized call to the web api from same (project)port number,with following jquery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ulEmployees = $('#ulEmployee');
    var username = $('#uname').val();
    var password = $('#pword').val();
    username = "male";
    password = "male";
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api/Employees',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(username + ':' + password)

            },

            success: function (data)
            {
                ulEmployees.empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, val) {

                    var fullName = val.FirstName + ''+val.gender + '' + val.LastName;
                    ulEmployees.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>');

                });
            },


        });
    });



    $('#btnclear').click(function(){

        ulEmployees.empty();

    });


    });

    });
```

if i made the request from different project it will not works

i use the following value for the url parameter in request

url: 'http://localhost:53099/api/Employees'

i have use the code for authorization in web api

```
<pre>
    [BasicAuthentication]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string gender = "ALL")
    {
       string username = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
      // string username = "male";
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            //int id = 4;
            //var entity = entities.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
            //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);

            switch (username.ToLower())
            {
                case "male":
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                        entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == "male").ToList());

                case "female":
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                       entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == "female").ToList());

                default:
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your webapi it gets hosted on your local IIS express on some particular port number. You will not be able to access this API from some other port number as it is not hosted on that port.

Comment: actally i am able to call unauthorized call from different port number(using cross domain ajax request).but  while calling from other port ,
actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization will have the value null